# Get MySQL records created in a time range?

Tags: php, datetime, mysql

I know this is obvious, but my date time row is in TEXT type, and i can't figure out how to fetch records that are:

- Inserted since a date until the present

  -- OR --
- Inserted in a specific day

Some of the failed attempts:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE DATE(date)=DATE(NOW()) // To get today's posts
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date>=CURDATE() // Still doesn't work.
```

P.S. The date row is in a `DateTime` format but in a `TEXT` type.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question but... What's the benefit of storing dates in `TEXT` columns?

Comment: Can you post a sample of what a date looks like in your table?

Comment: If it's possible/feasible, I would store them in a different format.  Its possible to use Álvaro's answer to get it working, but this will become horribly inefficient with large data sets.

Answer (score 2):

The function to parse strings into dates is STR_TO_DATE():

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

It assumes that the format is fixed and known. I don't know if that's the case.

Comment: A simple `CAST fieldname AS DATE` should be enough. The question why they are stored in TEXT fields is still valid though

Comment: @Pekka: Only if the dates are stored in a supported format: YYYY-MM-DD.  Otherwise, you have to use STR_TO_DATE...

Comment: @OMG he says `The date row is in a DateTime format but in a TEXT type.`

Comment: @Álvaro I'm pretty sure he means DATETIME values

Answer (score 0):

Use convert -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE convert(date, datetime) >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: Only if the dates are stored in a supported format: YYYY-MM-DD. Otherwise, you have to use STR_TO_DATE...